# What is a normal response time for a local asmx web service?

Tags: performance, iis, soap, asmx

I'm trying to optimize a webservice to be as fast as possible. I have the following sections in my machine.config running under IIS7.5 (.NET4) on a Windows Server 2008 box with 8 cores and 8Gb of RAM:

```
<system.web>
      <httpRuntime minFreeThreads="704" minLocalRequestFreeThreads="608" />
      <processModel autoConfig="true" maxWorkerThreads="100" maxIoThreads="100" minWorkerThreads="50" />
</system.web>

<system.net>
      <connectionManagement>
            <add address="*" maxconnection="96"/>
      </connectionManagement>
</system.net>
```

I have a .asmx web service which just waits 5 seconds and then returns. I then run the following C# code from a website on the same server:

```
CmsDataService service = new CmsDataService();
System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();

for (int i = 0; i < RequestCount; i++)
{
    threads.Add(new Thread(delegate()
        {
            service.sleepTest();
        }));
}

timer.Start();
foreach (var thread in threads)
{
    thread.Start();
}

while (threads.Any(t => t.IsAlive))
{
    // wait
}
timer.Stop();

Response.Clear();
Response.Write(timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

I get the following results back:

```
   10 requests in parallel averages = 5027ms
   100 requests in parallel averages = 10016ms
   1000 requests in parallel averages = 55175ms
```

The first results seems fine but the others seem quite slow. Is SOAP normally this slow or are there further configuration settings that can be tweaked?

Comment: If you're looking for performance, then why are you using ASMX? It's a legacy technology and.you should use WCF for all new development.

Comment: I agree - but its a constraint we have

Comment: Out of interest do you have any idea of what kind of performance increase we could expect from using WCF?

Comment: Note that ASMX is only barely supported. See [ASMX Forum has been Retired](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads)

Comment: Your performance improvement would depend on the other constraints you haven't mentioned, like what kind of clients you're using. .NET to .NET, you get to use binary transfers over TCP/IP instead of XML over SOAP. Much faster on its face. Buffering data path is much better as well.

Comment: Ok, I've implemented the service using WCF over Net.Tcp and its roughly the same speed. Also if I do 200 simultanious requests the application pool crashes and goes in to rapid fail connection mode with the following errors:

http://pastebin.com/LKv0WY7t
http://pastebin.com/y6ssYXFA
http://pastebin.com/JcdQ7xg6

web.config here:
http://pastebin.com/4RfjLRHn

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: Fixed it - the issue was with my testing. Creating too many instances of the service at once. Works fine when one instance with BeginSleepTest()

Comment: You've had an interesting experience going from ASMX to WCF so quickly. You should blog about it.

Comment: Too busy at the moment but may do one day.